# ngModuleType.ngModuleDef.id is undefined - Angular 8 issue when importing NguCarousel module

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, ngu-carousel

When I try and import the NguCarousel module, my app breaks because `ngModuleType.ngModuleDef` is undefined. If I comment out the import of NguCarousel module, the app works fine.
I've tried changing versions of the package but no luck. Currently I have v1.5.5 installed with Angular 8.

Any ideas why this module is missing this property?

js error:
[image]

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "webapi",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run WebApi:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-server": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.12",
    "@babel/compat-data": "^7.8.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@ngu/carousel": "^1.5.5",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.1.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "core-js": "^3.3.3",
    "echarts": "^4.9.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ngx-echarts": "^5.1.2",
    "ngx-spinner": "^9.0.2",
    "oidc-client": "^1.9.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "zone.js": "0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.24",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.2.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~12.11.6",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.5.5"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~5.20.0"
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AccountModule } from './account/account.module';
import { AccountRoutingModule } from './account/account.routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { NguCarouselModule } from '@ngu/carousel';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
        NguCarouselModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AccountModule,
        AccountRoutingModule,       
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'unauthorized', component: UnauthorizedComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
        ])
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthService,
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Will you remove `BrowserAnimationsModule` from AppModule and try it again?

Comment: same problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you add screenshot or log of error/issue that appears in console. Will help to debug

Comment: @Tejeshree just added screenshot. Thx!

Comment: Thanks, let me check. But i am curious about your ngModule. I dont see import for RouterModule, but you have used it in import[], similarly i don't see UnauthorizedComponent in declarations. Also, import { AccountModule } from './account/account.module; is missing ' in end. How is the app getting served?

Comment: @Tejeshree Hi, sorry, while I was condensing the app.module file to make it easier to read I missed a few imports. It should be corrected now

Comment: "`import { AccountModule } from './account/account.module;`" doesn't have a final apostrophe.

Answer (score 8):

I ran to the same error today for the same angular version (v8). it was caused by installing higher version of angular material (v12) when I noticed that I forget to specify the version I uninstall it using `npm uninstall` command then reinstall the correct version. this when the bug occurred for me.

**SOLUTION for my problem**

1. close the vs code
2. go to project path on file explorer
3. remove `node_modules` folder
4. open the project on vs code again
5. run command `npm i`

the node package manager will reinstall all packages with the correct version for you and this should solve the problem.

Comment: You can delete node_modules from within vs code, no need to close it.

Comment: Try this solution twice and it worked. (removed and re-installed node modules folder with package-lock.js)