# Angular project produces javascript error "core.js:23018 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')"

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

No changes have been made to the project, since it last compiled **except for upgrading VSCode**
Node: 16.13.0

I am now on 1.68.1 VSCode
Angular 8.3.1 is output of -v

the exact error is above.   When debugging through the section it points to,  it goes through imports: [, and it complains about LoadingBarHttpClientModule, and LoadingBarRouterModule, i remove those, but then complains about NgxsRootModule , so i give up at this point, not removing that.

in core.js this is the code where it will break in console

```
function registerNgModuleType(ngModuleType) {
    if (ngModuleType.ngModuleDef.id !== null) {
```

- i have tried to disable Angular Language Service but in this version there is no "checkbox" to do so, so i just went to extensions and disabled it.
- deleted node_modules, and npm install
- restored node_modules, and npm update
- restored node_modules,  and just run npm install

nothing

Also ever since my development machine was created, i cannot get ng new "commands" to run to create components or modules

If i do Windows Script Host pops up saying

\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@aungular\cli\bin\ng.js
line 1
char 1
invalid character

What gives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a dependency-version mismatch. You need to

1- Go to `C:\Users\${your_user_name_here}\AppData\Roaming\npm` and remove content manually if you are on Windows

2- Run `npm ci` to reinstall clean version packages

Also, you can follow [this thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67562858/ngmoduletype-ngmoduledef-id-is-undefined-angular-8-issue-when-importing-ngucar) since the same issue has been resolved similarly

Comment: only the npm ci was needed due to environment.  That was next if x other tries didnt work.

Thanks for responding and link.  Sometimes same errors lead you to incorrect searched top google solutions as you will see allot same up as the Angular Language Service being disabled in VSCode.

Comment: everything is working, (not in gitlib pipeline) but in package.json and lock it has

"@angular/core": "~8.2.8",

but in my node_modules it has 8.2.14 in /@angular/core/

?