# Angular dependency errors, during pipeline

Tags: node.js, angular, gitlab

The following chain of events had occured.

The Angular website application was pretty outdated, possibly v3 and was upgraded to 8.2.8, couldnt go all the way due to a dependency on mdbbootstrap which would require a rewrite in many places, made a change and the pipeline and check completed.

Coming back from another project i ran into this problem [Angular project produces javascript error "core.js:23018 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73264402/angular-project-produces-javascript-error-core-js23018-uncaught-typeerror-can), which was solved by npm -ci

Now after making my current changes, and sending off to gitlab pipeline, the following errors occur

```
npm ERR! While resolving: angular-date-value-accessor@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@8.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"~8.2.8" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"8.2.14" from @angular/animations@8.2.14
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"~8.2.8" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/animations@">=6.0.0 <9.0.0" from angular-calendar@0.26.11
npm ERR!     node_modules/angular-calendar
npm ERR!       angular-calendar@"^0.26.11" from the root project
npm ERR!   23 more (@angular/common, @angular/forms, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"^2.0.0" from angular-date-value-accessor@0.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/angular-date-value-accessor
npm ERR!   angular-date-value-accessor@"0.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@2.4.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"^2.0.0" from angular-date-value-accessor@0.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/angular-date-value-accessor
npm ERR!     angular-date-value-accessor@"0.0.1" from the root project
```

this is the gitlab-ci yaml

```
stage: build_staging
    image: node:lts
    script:
        - grep -rli '%COMMIT_HASH%' * | xargs -i@ sed -i "s/%COMMIT_HASH%/$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA/g" @
        - cd src/Web
        - npm install
        - npm run buildstaging
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - src/Web/dist/
        name: "$CI_JOB_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    only:
        refs:
            - develop

Deploy Web Staging:
    stage: deploy_staging
    image: xueshanf/awscli
    script:
        - cd src/Web
        - aws s3 sync ./dist s3://$STAGING_BUCKET_NAME/ --delete
        - echo "Invalidate index.html"
        - aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id $STAGING_DISTRIBUTION_ID --paths /index.html
    only:
        refs:
            - develop
```

(fyi its the build_staging that is the problem)

I am assuming what was fixed on my local machine is now no longer valid for npm install on npm:lts

What would be the proper course of direction, is it as simple as
npm ci( a very demanding operation)  instead of npm install ? or git clean ?

I also noticed, although everything works fine locally
in package.json and lock it has

"@angular/core": "~8.2.8",

but in my node_modules it has 8.2.14 in /@angular/core/

after running npm ci

Answer (score 0):

ok here is what i did to get it working.  This would not be a problem if ng commands would work so it could auto resolve dependency problems.   Each problem gitlab complained about i manually uninstalled and installed to see the error, and its dependency issue.  I upgraded either the component or dependency.  until all were gone.  Some components had to go completely, but none required a re-code of any usage (i think so far, it hasnt been fully tested).

Now when i finally resolved all these issues, i would get errors such as this

```
npm ERR! path /builds/0/WebSites/customerportal/CustomerPortal/src/Web/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js

npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /builds/0/WebSites/customerportal/CustomerPortal/src/Web/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
```

allot more all pointing to gyp, and some problem with python version.

I changed the version of the image to Node:14 in the yaml file, and the building stage would complete.  Also, the deploy stage would complete, (but the C# api layers time out on warning: 8 tasks failed to start